# Which App Store link do I use

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Before I uploaded the Xcode binary to iTunes Connect, I could only use the following link for app store to my app store page for game.

http://itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789

Now my app status is "pending developer release" and when I click on "view in app store" in iTunes Connect I now have another link...

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/App-Name/id123456789?gs=2&bh=3

Which link do I use now, does it make a difference even?

Comment: This really isn't a programming question.

Comment: Could you please answer anyways? I really need to know. It's not a programming question but it's an app store related question and I've seen a LOT of app store related questions on stack overflow

Comment: I suggest you ask on the Apple developer forums. That's a more appropriate place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

> https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/App-Name/id123456789?gs=2&bh=3

This URL is Standard App Store Links.

> http://itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789

This URL is short link.

The difference between these two is length. You can choose either one you like.

ref. Technical Q&A QA1633: Creating easy-to-read short links to the App Store for your apps and company 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html

Comment: Don't forget this part which will open itunes `?ls=1&mt=8`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you keep use before link